# I can't figure out why the header is not "responsive" in this "responsive" Wordpress theme

Tags: header, responsive

Here is the site-to-be (work in progress still)
http://www.fairhavenstorage.com/DRAFT

On a desktop screen it's fine, but on a mobile device, the site title and description do not budge. I added some custom CSS to allow the logo to display beside the site title - here is what I entered:

```
#logo .site-title, #logo .site-description {
    display: block !important;

}


.site-title {margin-top: 26px;}

#logo img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
}
```

And for the image on the right side of header, I entered this:

```
.header-widget {
 float: right;
 width: 200px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

It's not looking good on my iPhone and I'm unsure what to do. If anyone can suggest a fix, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try and deactvate or override existing css . There are @media queries in your existing css

Comment: I'm unsure HOW to do that without losing other styling features within the custom CSS?  Here is everything within our custom CSS file (using Canvas Wootheme)  It seems if only I could get the site title and description to "respond" and shrink, then the header would display better on a mobile device....?  Thank you!